# How to group lists inside a list by first element?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
big_list = [[0,5,70],[0,3,20],[0,4,60],[0,6,30],    
            [1,6,50],[1,4,30],[1,3,70],        
            [2,4,20],[2,5,40],
            [69,420,20]]
```

How do I turn it into this list, where all of the lists are grouped together into lists by the first number in every list:

```
big_list_sorted = [[[0,5,70],[0,3,20],[0,4,60],[0,6,30]],
                   [[1,6,50],[1,4,30],[1,3,70]],
                   [[2,4,20],[2,5,40]],
                   [[69,420,20]]]
```

Also, here I put lists in the original big_list in order for readability, but they would not be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [[Python 3.Docs]: itertools - Functions creating iterators for efficient looping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools).

Group the (inner) lists (via *groupby*), on their 1<sup>st</sup> element, in the **sorted** initial list:

> ```
> >>> import itertools
> >>>
> >>> big_list
> [[0, 5, 70], [0, 3, 50], [0, 4, 60], [0, 6, 30], [1, 6, 50], [1, 4, 30], [1, 3, 70], [2, 4, 20], [2, 5, 40], [69, 420, 20]]
> >>>
> >>> [list(item[1]) for item in itertools.groupby(sorted(big_list), key=lambda x: x[0])]
> [[[0, 3, 50], [0, 4, 60], [0, 5, 70], [0, 6, 30]], [[1, 3, 70], [1, 4, 30], [1, 6, 50]], [[2, 4, 20], [2, 5, 40]], [[69, 420, 20]]]
> ```

As a side note (might be a *typo*), the 1<sup>st</sup> element in the desired output (`[0, 3, 20]`) is not present in the input.

Comment: Yes, there were some typos, sorry for that. Thank you for your solution, works like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome! :) BTW, I noticed that previously you marked as solutions 2 incorrect answers (that were only working on the given example).

Comment: Yes, I did. And after I tested them I realised yours was the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can group lists in a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) by their first element and get the result using [`.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=values#dict.values):

```
groups = {}
for l in big_list:
    groups.setdefault(l[0], []).append(l)

big_list_sorted = list(groups.values())
print(big_list_sorted)
# [[[0, 5, 70], [0, 3, 50], [0, 4, 60], [0, 6, 30]], [[1, 6, 50], [1, 4, 30], [1, 3, 70]], [[2, 4, 20], [2, 5, 40]], [[69, 420, 20]]]
```

Comment: I love this. No imports, and does exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```py
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g) for _, g in groupby(big_list, lambda l: l[0])]
[[[0, 5, 70], [0, 3, 50], [0, 4, 60], [0, 6, 30]], [[1, 6, 50], [1, 4, 30], [1, 3, 70]], [[2, 4, 20], [2, 5, 40]], [[69, 420, 20]]]
```

Note: you can void to use `list`, it's there only to make the output more readable as groupby returns an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to accomplish this.

First you sort the array by the first element.

```
big_list = sorted(big_list)
```

Next you apply `groupby` to split them into subarrays keyed on the first element.

```
itertools.groupby(big_list, key=lambda x:x[0])
```

At this point you have something that looks like

```
[(0, <itertools._grouper object at 0x107bcf390>), (1, <itertools._grouper object at 0x107bcf310>), (2, <itertools._grouper object at 0x107bcf250>), (69, <itertools._grouper object at 0x107bcf2d0>)]
```

In the tuple, the grouper objects at index 1 contains the elements matching the key at index 0. Now you can just create an array using index 1 of each tuple.

```
[list(g) for i, g in itertools.groupby(big_list, lambda x: x[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a minor stylistic thing but you can avoid the ugly `lambda x: x[0]` many answers are opting for and use `operator.itemgetter` instead.

```
from random import shuffle
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

big_list = [[0,5,70],[0,3,50],[0,4,60],[0,6,30],    
            [1,6,50],[1,4,30],[1,3,70],        
            [2,4,20],[2,5,40],
            [69,420,20]]

shuffle(big_list)

[*map(list,map(itemgetter(1),groupby(sorted(big_list),itemgetter(0))))]

# [[[0, 3, 50], [0, 4, 60], [0, 5, 70], [0, 6, 30]], [[1, 3, 70], [1, 4, 30], [1, 6, 50]], [[2, 4, 20], [2, 5, 40]], [[69, 420, 20]]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a custom sort based on the first element of each list.

```
big_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

You can read about sorting here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting